# SED - Regex fails

Tags: regex, bash, sed, pcre

Given the following files:

**input_file**:

```
if_line1
if_line2
```

**template_file_1**:

```
temp_file_line1
temp_file_line2

##regex_match## <= must be replaced by input_file

temp_file_line3
```

**template_file_2**:

```
temp_file_line1
temp_file_line2

{my_file.global} <= must be replaced by input_file

temp_file_line3
```

**output_file**:

```
temp_file_line1
temp_file_line2

if_line1
if_line2

temp_file_line3
```

For **template_file_1** the following sed command works:

```
sed -n -e '/##regex_match##/{r input_file' -e 'b' -e '}; p' template_file_1 > output_file
```

However, for **template_file_2** the analog sed command fails:

```
sed -r -n -e '/(?<={).+\.global(?=})/{r input_file' -e 'b' -e '}; p' template_file_2 > output_file
```

sed complains the regular expression was invalid

The given regex is at least PCRE valid, for example `grep -oP '(?<={).+\.global(?=})' template_file_2` works. Any idea how to deal with that?

Comment: `sed` does not support PCRE, only POSIX BRE/ERE regex.

Comment: Do you have maybe an idea how this could be realised without lookarounds? Detecting {my_file.global} and extracting my_file.global, without the curly brackets?

Comment: Perl supports Perl regular expressions with lookarounds and whatnot. Why do you need sed?

Comment: Well, it seems to work with `/\{.+\.global}/`, `sed -r -n -e '/\{.+\.global}/{r input_file' -e 'b' -e '}; p' template_file_2 > output_file`

Comment: @glennjackman Actually, OP is using `-r`, it is the same as `-E`. I understand `-E` is more portable, but it works for OP, and for me as well.

Comment: d'oh, I glazed over that.

Comment: @choroba: Could that fit into a onliner in Perl as well?

Comment: Depends on your line length :)

Comment: You don't need to use lookarounds if the regexp is just being used to match lines. They're only needed if you need to do something with the part of the line that matches, like replace it with something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perl one-liners:

```
perl -pe 'do {local $/; open $f, "<input_file"; $_ = <$f>; close $f} if /\{.+?\.global\}/' template_file_2
```

or perhaps this one,  not "pure" perl

```
perl -ne 'if (/\{.+?\.global\}/) {system("cat","input_file")} else {print}' template_file_2
```

Using CPAN modules can make this really tidy:

```
perl -MPath::Tiny -pe '$_ = path("input_file")->slurp if /\{.+?\.global\}/' template_file_2
```

Answer (score 2):

idk exactly what that PCRE is intended to do but taking a guess at it, this will work using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{new=new s $0; s=ORS; next} /##regex_match##/{$0=new} 1' input_file template_file_1
temp_file_line1
temp_file_line2

if_line1
if_line2

temp_file_line3

$ awk 'NR==FNR{new=new s $0; s=ORS; next} /\{[^.{}]+\.global}/{$0=new} 1' input_file template_file_2
temp_file_line1
temp_file_line2

if_line1
if_line2

temp_file_line3
```

Comment: As always great solutions sir.